# SQLite3 Delete row using auto ID using Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm using Python, Pandas and SQLite3. I've read data from a CSV into a Dataframe and then used to_sql to store the data from Pandas in a SQLite3 database table.

I didn't set an index so SQLite3 used an auto index for each row.

Is it possible for me to use that auto index when I want to delete a row from my Python code?

I want to use something like "DELETE FROM prod_backup WHERE id=4;" but I'm getting an error saying no column called id. When I use a database browser, the auto index column doesn't actually have a column name so I'm not sure how to actually reference it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When you create the table, you need to include a column like `id INT AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: Thats great, thanks Barmar